# Django return HLS streaming to frontend

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, backend, http-live-streaming

I have encountered an issue during develop HLS live streaming through Django restframework.
Currently, I have a shell script that generates HLS files(m3u8), and now I am confused about how to respond the generated HLS files to the frontend so that the user able to view the HLS streaming from web.

I did a little bit research on this, looks some developers suggest use Django serve, but I am confused will it be enough if I only return the m3u8 to the frontend.

[HLS source files generated from ffmpeg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1Li9.png)

Comment: Same issue here. What I know so far that its required to generate a unique access grant for each snipped you deliver. Are you using S3 to serve your .ts files ?